# Javascript Cookie Code not storing a cookie/reading a null cookie value?

Tags: javascript, cookies, email-verification

I took this code from the Headfirst Javascript book, for cookies.  But for some reason it's not working with my browsers.  I'm mainly using chrome and ff, and i have local cookies enabled in chrome.  Help??

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function checkCookie(){
    var name = eatCookie("yahooEmail");
    if(name)
        document.getElementById("emailVerf").style.visibility="hidden";
    else
        document.getElementById("emailBody").style.visibility="hidden";
}



function writeCookie(name, val, days){

    var expires = "";

    if(days){
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + val + expires + "; path=/";

}

function eatCookie(val){
    var search = val + "=";
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');

    for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++){
        var c = cookies[i];
        while(c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c=c.substring(1, c.length);
        if(c.indexOf(search) == 0)
            return c.substring(search.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;

}

function verEmail(val){

    var regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9][@yahoo.com]";
    var exp = new RegExp(regex);

    if(!exp.test(val)){
        document.getElementById("email").style.color="red";
        alert("Please enter a valid Yahoo email address.");
        }
    else{
        writeCookie("yahooEmail", val, 7);
        document.getElementById("emailVerf").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("emailBody").style.visibility="visible";
        }
}

</script>
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? reading cookies? writing cookies? elsewhere? do you get any errors?

Comment: @mkilmanas It's not working either reading or writing the cookie.  When i read the cookie, it returns null, so every time i load the page it acts like there is no cookie.  And the ayahoo was a typo, but i changed it from what it was before. Even with it spelled correctly it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing a cookie named "ayahooEmail" but reading one called "yahooEmail"

Comment: Well, I don't know what to tell you: I can write a cookie called "yahooEmail" and read it just fine using `writeCookie` and `eatCookie`. The *only* thing that comes to mind is that you are not using `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the cookie value before you write it, and `decodeURIComponent`when you read it. (Remember cookie values cannot contain equal signs, spaces, semicolons, and several other characters.)

Comment: @portugusto_programmer: In fact, I am appalled at the [Headfirst JavaScript code for using cookies](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfjs/ch03/irock/cookie.js) since it does not encode/decode values. Come on!

Comment: I will definitely try that out.  That's probably the problem. Thank you.